# Spring Data Neo4j: Indefinite waiting for RWLock without DeadlockDetectedException

Tags: java, concurrency, neo4j, deadlock, spring-data-neo4j

In my project I use Spring Data Neo4j (3.4.2.RELEASE) with the AspectJ-based "advanced mapping" mode using an embedded database.
I am also using the AspectJ-based transaction management via`@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)`

In my application I am experiencing deadlocks in cases where concurrent reads/writes to the database are supposed to occur. I am not receiving a `DeadlockDetectedException` though but instead see that one thread indefinitely waits for `RWLock`. Shortly after that all remaining threads will wait on the first thread and the application comes to a halt from which it doesn't recover. The other threads may also have already aquired locks, but as I can't see that I am not sure about it.

Stacktrace of locked thread:

```
Thread [Processing-XXX] (Suspended) 
owns: SeasonOfCompetitionRepositoryImpl  (id=134)   
waiting for: RWLock  (id=174)   
Object.wait(long) line: not available [native method]   
RWLock(Object).wait() line: 502 [local variables unavailable]   
RWLock.acquireWriteLock(Object) line: 388   
LockManagerImpl.getWriteLock(Object, Object) line: 66   
CommunityLockClient.acquireExclusive(Locks$ResourceType, long) line: 116    
LockingStatementOperations.relationshipCreate(KernelStatement, int, long, long) line: 287   
OperationsFacade.relationshipCreate(int, long, long) line: 866  
NodeProxy.createRelationshipTo(Node, RelationshipType) line: 559    
DelegatingGraphDatabase.getOrCreateRelationship(Node, Node, RelationshipType, Direction, Map<String,Object>) line: 298  
Neo4jTemplate.getOrCreateRelationship(Node, Node, RelationshipType, Direction, Map<String,Object>) line: 772    
RelationshipHelper.createSingleRelationship(Node, Node) line: 198   
RelationshipHelper.createAddedRelationships(Node, Set<Node>) line: 154  
RelatedToSingleFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToSingleFieldAccessor(RelatedToFieldAccessor).createAddedRelationships(Node, Set<Node>) line: 78 
RelatedToSingleFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToSingleFieldAccessor.setValue(Object, Object, MappingPolicy) line: 68   
NodeEntityState(DefaultEntityState<STATE>).setValue(Neo4jPersistentProperty, Object, MappingPolicy) line: 113   
DetachedEntityState<STATE>.setValue(Neo4jPersistentProperty, Object, MappingPolicy) line: 181   
DetachedEntityState<STATE>.setValue(Field, Object, MappingPolicy) line: 145 
SeasonOfCompetition.season_aroundBody21$advice(SeasonOfCompetition, SeasonOfCompetition, Season, JoinPoint, Neo4jNodeBacking, NodeBacked, Object, AroundClosure, JoinPoint) line: 266   
SeasonOfCompetition.setSeason_aroundBody22(SeasonOfCompetition, Season) line: 108   
SeasonOfCompetition$AjcClosure23.run(Object[]) line: 1  
AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(Object, AroundClosure) line: 66    
AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation() line: 72  
AnnotationTransactionAspect(TransactionAspectSupport).invokeWithinTransaction(Method, Class<?>, InvocationCallback) line: 281   
AnnotationTransactionAspect(AbstractTransactionAspect).ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(Object, AroundClosure, JoinPoint$StaticPart) line: 70    
SeasonOfCompetition.setSeason(Season) line: 95  
SeasonOfCompetitionRepositoryImpl.getOrCreate_aroundBody0(SeasonOfCompetitionRepositoryImpl, Season, Competition) line: 32  
SeasonOfCompetitionRepositoryImpl$AjcClosure1.run(Object[]) line: 1 
AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(Object, AroundClosure) line: 66    
AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation() line: 72  
AnnotationTransactionAspect(TransactionAspectSupport).invokeWithinTransaction(Method, Class<?>, InvocationCallback) line: 281   
AnnotationTransactionAspect(AbstractTransactionAspect).ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(Object, AroundClosure, JoinPoint$StaticPart) line: 70    
SeasonOfCompetitionRepositoryImpl.getOrCreate(Season, Competition) line: 26
```

This is the part of a custom RepositoryExtension that is supposed to create unique `SeasonOfCompetition`s for the given parameters:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public synchronized SeasonOfCompetition getOrCreate(Season season, Competition competition)
{
    String uri = buildUri(season, competition);
    SeasonOfCompetition soc = getOrCreateByUri(uri);
    if(soc.getSeason() == null)
    {
        soc.setSeason(season);
    }
    if(soc.getCompetition() == null)
    {
        soc.setCompetition(competition);
    }
    return soc;
}
```

Note that I've already played around a bit with `@Transactional` and `sychronized` - both of which I initially didn't use because I think (but am not sure) that they are not required here.

This is a selection of the domain entity `SeasonOfCompetition` in which the thread gets stuck:

```
@NodeEntity
public class SeasonOfCompetition extends UriEntity
{
    @RelatedTo(type = "inSeason", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Season season;

    @Transactional
    public void setSeason(Season season)
    {
        this.season = season;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I was under the assumption that access to the graph database via SDN is thread safe and that I don't require any special handling except for the use of transactions.
Advice on how to debug this or how to make it throw a `DeadlockDetectedException` in this case is welcome as well.

I've previously also had other concurrency related problems (duplicate entities that are meant to be unique, duplicate relationshipts, etc) and don't fully undertand how else I need to treat this. Input on how to implement a thread-safe #getOrCreate for NodeEntities and Relationships is appreciated.

Edit:
I've tried to implement a `MERGE`-query based version of #getOrCreate that doesn't use any custom synchronization as suggested by @cybersam:

```
@Override
@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public T getOrCreateByUri(String uri)
{
    checkArgument(!StringUtils.isEmpty(uri));

    Class<T> clazz = getEntityType();
    String queryString = "MERGE (n:" + clazz.getSimpleName() + " {uri: {uri}}) RETURN n";
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("uri", uri);
    Node node = (Node) template.getGraphDatabase().queryEngine().query(queryString, parameters).single().get( "n" );
    template.postEntityCreation(node, clazz);
    T result = (T) template.convert(node, clazz);
    return result.persist();
}
```

This however fails to create unique nodes. A simple test that creates 100 threads and calls this in parallel fails because multiple nodes are created.
This might be related to `result.persist()` but without that the returned entities are not attached to the graph and some information is missing.

Answer (score 1):

The [neo4j documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-deadlocks.html) contains this warning:

> **Important**
>
> Deadlocks caused by the use of other synchronization than the locks
>   managed by Neo4j can still happen. Since all operations in the Neo4j
>   API are thread safe unless specified otherwise, there is no need for
>   external synchronization. Other code that requires synchronization
>   should be synchronized in such a way that it never performs any Neo4j
>   operation in the synchronized block.

`getOrCreate()`, which performs Neo4j operations, is currently `synchronized`. So, it is possible that the deadlock is actually caused by your own code's Java synchronization. You will need to re-design your code to avoid using Java synchronization when performing Neo4j operations.

Comment: But how does Spring Data Neo4j fit into the picture? This is an additional layer on top of Neo4j. How does one instantiate unique entities there?

Comment: See this part of the documentation: neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-unique-nodes.html.